# Strategies for finding language of a stored procedure in Postgresql without pg_lang entry

Tags: sql, postgresql, schema

I've got a procedure with a prolang of 16386, which does not correspond to any of the entries in pg_lang; what other possible places can I look to find what language this is?

What other strategies should I use to find the language?

Comment: Do you mean ["pg_language"](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/catalog-pg-language.html)?

Comment: Are you sure the language doesn't exist? When the language doesn't exist, you can't have functions depending on it. So you must have a corrupt database (restore from backup) or looking at the wrong place.
SELECT oid, * FROM pg_language;

Answer (score 0):

If the language exists:

The simplest approach is to log in with psql and type:

```
\df+ function_name
```

This will list all of the functions with the same name, their arguments, schemas, source code, and languages.

One could look directly in the system catalogs (pg_proc and pg_language) but one issue here is that these do change sometimes between major versions so it is probably better to rely on the psql info functions which are tied to the same major version as your db server.

If the language does not exist:

```
select * from pg_proc where ....
```

gives you everything about the language (its source code, linker symbol, etc.)

From that you should be able to find out what language it is.  16386 is not one of the built-in ones, so it must have been user defined and you will have to do some digging.

For example, something pointing at a .jar would suggest pl/java.  Source code will likely be identifiable as a language (you should be able to see whether it is pl/ruby or the like).

One possibility is that this could be from a botched upgrade and a no-longer-maintained language handler.